# PHP arrays and array objects

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have a PHP array that looks like this When var_dumped

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
array (size=8)
  'Product_code' => string 'CAB55FR' (length=7)
  'Elapsed' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Count' => string '42' (length=2)
  'Scrap' => string '0' (length=1)
  'ScrapPercentage' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'Perhour' => null
  'Target' => float 40
  'Eff' => string '105%' (length=4)
1 => 
array (size=8)
  'Product_code' => string 'MSTACK60' (length=8)
  'Elapsed' => string '0.05' (length=4)
  'Count' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Scrap' => string '0' (length=1)
  'ScrapPercentage' => null
  'Perhour' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'Target' => string 'No Target set' (length=13)
   'Eff' => string 'No Target set' (length=13)
```

However what i want the array to look like is this

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'Product_code' => string 'CAB55FR' (length=7)
  public 'Elapsed' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'Count' => string '42' (length=2)
  public 'Scrap' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'ScrapPercentage' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  public 'Perhour' => null
1 => 
object(stdClass)[9]
  public 'Product_code' => string 'MSTACK60' (length=8)
  public 'Elapsed' => string '0.05' (length=4)
  public 'Count' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'Scrap' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'ScrapPercentage' => null
  public 'Perhour' => string '0.00' (length=4)
```

To create the first array i am using this snippet of code

```
 $todayarray[] = Array(
            'Product_code' => $v->Product_code,
            'Elapsed' => $v->Elapsed,
            'Count' => $v->Count,
            'Scrap' => $v->Scrap,
            'ScrapPercentage' => $v->ScrapPercentage,
            'Perhour' => $v->Perhour,
            'Target' => $value,
            'Eff' => $eff
        );
```

this is run in a foreach, What would be the best way to get the array this is generating to look like the second example?

Comment: `$todayarray[] = (object) Array( ... );` would cast the array to an object and achieve what you want. See : http://3v4l.org/VWd0b

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ Sure does thank you very much, post as an answer and ill upvore and mark as answer

Comment: Soooo... you have an *object* (`$v`), which you're going to great lengths to turn into an array, yet what you really want is the original object? Then just don't do all this array conversion...?! I don't get it.

Comment: @deceze The original object comes from PDO::Fetchall, i need to add and change a few things in the results but the existing code to work with the output of the Fetch all uses the original object, so for me this is much easier just to do what i need and put it back as an object

Comment: @Oisian2 added as an answer. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @oisian: why so why not fetchObject()? It fetches a stdclass by default.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to just cast the array to an object.

```
$todayarray[] = (object) Array( ... );
```

See [a working demo](http://3v4l.org/VWd0b).

Read more about type casting on the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($top_array as $item) {
   $object = news stdClass;
   $object->... = $item[...];
   $object->... = $item[...];
   ...
   object_array[] = $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$todayarr = new stdClass;

$properties = array('prop1', 'prop2');

foreach ($properties as $p)
    $todayarr->$p = 'some value of property ' . $p;


var_dump($todayarr);
```